# writing zip file to file in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a method for zipping:

```
    (defn zip-project [project-id notebooks files]
  (with-open [out (ByteArrayOutputStream.)
              zip (ZipOutputStream. out)]
    (doseq [nb notebooks]
      (.putNextEntry zip (ZipEntry. (str "Notebooks/" (:notebook/name nb) ".bkr")))
      (let [nb-json (:notebook/contents nb)
            bytes (.getBytes nb-json)]
        (.write zip bytes))
      (.closeEntry zip))
    (doseq [{:keys [name content]} files]
      (.putNextEntry zip (ZipEntry. (str "Files/" name)))
      (io/copy content zip)
      (.closeEntry zip))
    (.finish zip)
    (.toByteArray out)))
```

after I make a zip I want to save it into the file something like /tmp/sample/sample.zip, but I cannot seem to make it. here is what I am doing:

```
(defn create-file! [path zip]
  (let [f (io/file path)]
    (io/make-parents f)
    (io/copy zip f)
    true))
```

The problem is, when I run unzip from terminal it says that zip file is empty and if I unzip it using Archive utility it extracts with cpgz extension.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My hunch is that the problem is that you call `(.toByteArray out)(.toByteArray out)` inside the `with-open` so some bytes may still be unflushed in the ZipOutputStream. So you'd rather refactor to `(.toByteArray (with-open [...] ... out))`.

Comment: When I run `(create-file! "/tmp/sample/sample.zip" (zip-project 1 [{:notebook/name "Hello" :notebook/contents "yadada"}] [{:name "name" :content "content"}]))` the file `/tmp/sample/sample.zip` is created. When I unzip it I see a folder `Notebooks` with the file `Hello.bkr` with "yadada" as content. So for those dummy values it works fine on my machine. What `notebooks` and `files`  do you pass to `zip-project`? Can you add them to the question?

Answer (score 3):

You will need essentially 4 things

1. Import everything (normally you would use `(ns ...)` but you can run this in the repl

   ```
   (import 'java.io.FileOutputStream)
   (import 'java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
   (import 'java.io.ZipOutputStream)
   (import 'java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream)
   (import 'java.util.zip.ZipEntry)
   ```
2. You need a way to initialize the stream. This can be done nicely with the `->` macro:

   ```
   (defn zip-stream
     "Opens a ZipOutputStream over the given file (as a string)"
     [file]
     (-> (FileOutputStream. file)
         BufferedOutputStream.
         ZipOutputStream.))
   ```
3. You need a way to create/close entries in the `ZipOutputStream`

   ```
   (defn create-zip-entry
     "Create a zip entry with the given name. That will be the name of the file inside the zipped file."
     [stream entry-name]
     (.putNextEntry stream (ZipEntry. entry-name)))
   ```
4. Finally you need a way to write your content.

   ```
   (defn write-to-zip
     "Writes a string to a zip stream as created by zip-stream"
     [stream str]
     (.write stream (.getBytes str)))
   ```
5. Putting it all together:

   ```
   (with-open [stream (zip-stream "coolio.zip")]
     (create-zip-entry stream "foo1.txt")
     (write-to-zip stream "Hello Foo1")
     (.closeEntry stream) ;; don't forget to close entries
     (create-zip-entry stream "foo2.txt")
     (write-to-zip stream "Hello Foo 2")
     (.closeEntry stream))
   ```
6. The result:

[image: The result]